# Migrate Java Web project from Maven to Ant

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, web, ant

I have a Maven Web Application with Spring MVC and I need to convert it into a Java Web Application build with Ant. I am using Netbeans. The path structure should be the same? What configuration files should I add, remove, or change?

The reason of the change is beacuse I need to run the application without Internet connection.

Comment: Have you considered [gradle](https://gradle.org/) instead of ant?

Comment: You don't need to switch to Ant for that reason. If you already have the dependencies downloaded then you can run maven with the -o option which means it builds offline.

Comment: You don't need the Internet to run the application. You only need the Internet for the initial compilation. All dependencies will be loaded into your local Maven repository, and future compiles should not access the Internet. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is even a goal for it http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html :-)

Comment: Start using a repository manager and the problem with the internet is done if you don't like to checkin all the jars you need into your version control. You can also use a local repository only by using `mvn --off-line...` ...